# How to create custom side menu in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a custom side menu in Flutter like this
[image: What I want]

I created the side menu bar using this code

```
class _SideMenuState extends State<SideMenu> {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: 101.0,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: AppColors.mainBlueColor,
          ),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: List.generate(
                  icon.length,
                  (index) => Tooltip(
                    message: titles[index],
                    child: NavBarItem(
                      icon: icon[index],
                      selected: selected[index],
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          select(index);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

But I'm confused about how to code the other menu that appears when the user clicks the sidebar menu. Here's how my menu looks like now:

[image: Side Menu]
If anyone has any ideas, kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "curved labeled navigation bar" package to achieve the desired functionality.

https://pub.dev/packages/curved_labeled_navigation_bar

Comment: But it's nav bar and I want it like side menu